# Information preserved in the kernel mean embedding

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, embeddings, kernel-mean-embedding

I have recently been introduced to the kernel mean embedding of distributions, that is the map
$$\mu: \mathcal{M}^{1}_{+}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{H} \\ \mu(P) := \int \phi(x) dP(x)$$
where $K$ is a positive definite kernel with feature map $\phi$ and corresponding RKHS given by $\mathcal{H}$. I am now interested in what $\mu(P)$ tells us about the distribution $P$.

From what I have read online, there is the notion of characteristic kernels, for which the map $\mu$ is injective. The Gaussian RBF kernel satisfies this property, whereas polynomial kernels do not. Intuitively this is clear to me, however I have not found a formal proof of it. Perhaps someone has a reference.